# Flag to stop echo in php

Tags: php, echo

Is there a flag to hide echo statements in a php function. I want to be able to control when the echo statements are printed.  Here is a sample function where I want a switch to control the echo statements.

```
function create_liturgical_calendar($year) {
    if ( !isset($year) ) {
        $year = get_year();
    }

    global $add_data, $skip;

    echo "<div style='border-bottom: 4px solid #404040;'>year ".$year." add data ".$add_data." skip ".$skip."</div><div style='height: 92%; overflow: auto;'><br/>";

    $Baptism_of_the_Lord_date = get_Baptism_of_the_Lord($year); 
    echo 'Baptism of the Lord '.$Baptism_of_the_Lord_date->month.' '.$Baptism_of_the_Lord_date->date.' '.$Baptism_of_the_Lord_date->year.' '.$Baptism_of_the_Lord_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Ash_Wednesday_date = get_Ash_Wednesday_date($year);
    echo 'Ash Wednesday will be '.$Ash_Wednesday_date->month.' '.$Ash_Wednesday_date->date.' '.$Ash_Wednesday_date->year.' '.$Ash_Wednesday_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Annunciation_date = get_Annunciation_date($year);
    echo 'Annunciation will be '.$Annunciation_date->month.' '.$Annunciation_date->date.' '.$Annunciation_date->year.' '.$Annunciation_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Palm_Sunday_date = get_Palm_Sunday_date($year);
    echo 'Palm Sunday will be '.$Palm_Sunday_date->month.' '.$Palm_Sunday_date->date.' '.$Palm_Sunday_date->year.' '.$Palm_Sunday_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Holy_Thursday_date = get_Holy_Thursday_date($year);
    echo 'Holy Thursday will be '.$Holy_Thursday_date->month.' '.$Holy_Thursday_date->date.' '.$Holy_Thursday_date->year.' '.$Holy_Thursday_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Good_Friday_date = get_Good_Friday_date($year);
    echo 'Good Friday will be '.$Good_Friday_date->month.' '.$Good_Friday_date->date.' '.$Good_Friday_date->year.' '.$Good_Friday_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Holy_Saturday_date = get_Holy_Saturday_date($year);
    echo 'Holy Saturday will be '.$Holy_Saturday_date->month.' '.$Holy_Saturday_date->date.' '.$Holy_Saturday_date->year.' '.$Holy_Saturday_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Easter_date = get_Easter_date($year); 
    echo 'Easter will be '.$Easter_date->month.' '.$Easter_date->date.' '.$Easter_date->year.' '.$Easter_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Divine_Mercy_date = get_Divine_Mercy_date($year);
    echo 'Divine Mercy will be '.$Divine_Mercy_date->month.' '.$Divine_Mercy_date->date.' '.$Divine_Mercy_date->year.' '.$Divine_Mercy_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Ascension_date = get_Ascension_date($year);
    echo 'Ascension will be '.$Ascension_date->month.' '.$Ascension_date->date.' '.$Ascension_date->year.' '.$Ascension_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Pentecost_date = get_Pentecost_date($year);
    echo 'Pentecost will be '.$Pentecost_date->month.' '.$Pentecost_date->date.' '.$Pentecost_date->year.' '.$Pentecost_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Most_Holy_Trinity_date = get_Most_Holy_Trinity_date($year);
    echo 'Most Holy Trinity will be '.$Most_Holy_Trinity_date->month.' '.$Most_Holy_Trinity_date->date.' '.$Most_Holy_Trinity_date->year.' '.$Most_Holy_Trinity_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Corpus_Christi_date = get_Corpus_Christi_date($year);
    echo 'Corpus Christi will be '.$Corpus_Christi_date->month.' '.$Corpus_Christi_date->date.' '.$Corpus_Christi_date->year.' '.$Corpus_Christi_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Most_Sacred_Heart_date = get_Most_Sacred_Heart_date($year);
    echo 'Most Sacred Heart will be '.$Most_Sacred_Heart_date->month.' '.$Most_Sacred_Heart_date->date.' '.$Most_Sacred_Heart_date->year.' '.$Most_Sacred_Heart_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Immaculate_Heart_date = get_Immaculate_Heart_date($year);
    echo 'Immaculate Heart will be '.$Immaculate_Heart_date->month.' '.$Immaculate_Heart_date->date.' '.$Immaculate_Heart_date->year.' '.$Immaculate_Heart_date->date_string.'<br/>';

    $Christ_the_King_date = get_Christ_the_King_date($year);
    echo 'Christ the King will be '.$Christ_the_King_date->month.' '.$Christ_the_King_date->date.' '.$Christ_the_King_date->year.' '.$Christ_the_King_date->date_string.'<br/>';

}
```

Comment: As I understood, you are generating strings rather than queries from a table.  I suggest to create a database schema where you save, your calendar, dates, and other stuff related to holly calendar and events.  By doing so, you can flag each date or event and when deploying,  you can condition the **echo** based on each row`s flag.  Also can condition the styling, based on flags, due dates, type of events,...

Comment: Why do you need to 'stop' echos? Why can't you just use switch, if etc to control which strings echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like since there isn't a general flag to toggle echo, the best thing is to write a function.

```
  $print = true;

  function print_echo ( $print_text ) {
         if ( $print ) echo $print_text;
  }

  print_echo ('Print if true');
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to stop an echo is to use output buffering. e.g.

```
ob_start();
echo 'Hello World';
ob_end_clean();
```

Produces no output.

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php

Comment: True, but I don't think that helps. That makes the output always off in his case - just as though he removed the `echo` to begin with. He still needs a condition to change the output buffering, so he may as well conditionally echo things. If his functions are properly divided up, a simple if statement should do exactly what he needs.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm trying to answer the main question i.e. how to prevent echos in a php statement. I agree though that it's unclear why he'd actually need to do that given the problem presented. If he provides further info I'll update/delete my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ....your condition ) {
  echo ...
}
elseif {
  echo ...
}
else {
  echo ...
}
//etc...

or

switch ($someVar) {
  case 0:
    echo ...
  break;
  case 1:
    echo ...
  break;
  case 2:
    echo ...
  break;
}
```

Conditions are your flag... If you want the function to not echo anything, then setup a condition and use it however it makes the most sense.

```
function echoThings() {
  echo //etc
}

if (!$echoOff) {
  echoThings();
}
```

then just set `$echoOff = true` when you need to disable the function.